# Using C or C++ to copy a non-text file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, copy

If I write a program in C or C++ to copy a non-text file (.mp3, .avi, etc.) from one location to another in Windows/CMD Prompt, am I realistically relying on the Windows API to do all the work for me? Copying a text file is one thing, I can open it and copy character by character or string by string. Could somebody give me a brief rundown (If you have reference links, even better. I'm only asking because I couldn't find anything reasonable to explain it.) on how a non-text file copying program would work?

Thanks folks!

Comment: You do know that files can be opened in one of two modes: Text or binary?

Comment: Copying characters by characters or string by string is also byte copying. So, copying a non-text file, you open it in binary mode and copy the byte by byte.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006797/tried-and-true-simple-file-copying-code-in-c

Answer (score 7):

[CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has been good enough for me

```
BOOL WINAPI CopyFile(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
  _In_  BOOL bFailIfExists
);
```

(from msdn)

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE *inFile, *outFile;

inFile = fopen(inFilePath, "rb");
outFile = fopen(outFilePath, "wb");

long getFileSize(FILE *file) {
  long curPos, endPos;
  curPos = ftell(file);
  fseek(file, 0, 2);
  endPos = ftell(file);
  fseek(file, curPos, 0);
  return endPos;
}

size_t bufferLength = getFileSize(inFile);
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

void copyFile(FILE *inFile, FILE *outFile) {
  fread(buffer, bufferLength, 1, inFile);
  fwrite(buffer, bufferLength, 1, outFile);
}

copyFile(inFile, outFile);
fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);
```

`inFilePath` and `outFilePath` must both be pointers to a character which contains the path to the respective file.

The above code is portable, in case you're looking for something that isn't platform specific. I'll leave the error handling to you. Also, this was written in a hurry so please do review it before use.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, every file is a sequence of bytes. You can copy byte by byte(or bigger chunks) any file. But you should not disturb data inside the file. Open file in binary mode and copy. If you use this method your program will works for any platform with small changes. If you use windows API's that restrict your program to windows platform only.

Comment: Do not copy byte by byte. Do it in bigger chunks as it is more efficent