# How do you convert binary file to bytes?

Tags: c, unix, ftp, binaryfiles, fread

I'm building a simple ftp which allows the user to ask basic commands of a unix server (eg: `cd home/file/`) and upload files to the server and download files from the server. I have gotten the basic commands to work and print between client and server, but copying files that aren't text is a challenge.

My current code for the `get` function is as follows:

**Cli6.c**

```
    else if (strcmp(tokens[0], "get") == 0) {
        char *filecpy = convertfile("mtg.jpg");
        printf("%s .... %d\n", filecpy, strlen(filecpy));
    }
```

**FTP.c**

```
char *convertfile(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fileptr; 
    char *buffer;
    long filen;
    size_t result;
     
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
     
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    filen = ftell(fileptr);
    rewind(fileptr);
     
    printf("File size: %d\n", filen);
     
    buffer = (char *)malloc(filen + 1); // this is only allocating 8bytes
     
    fread(buffer,filen, 1,fileptr);
    printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);
    close(fileptr);
     
     
    /*
    char *c; 
    char *buffer;
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    while (c != EOF) {
        fread(&c, (size_t)1, (size_t)1, fileptr);
        buffer[c]++;
        c = fgetc(fileptr);
        sprintf(buffer[strlen(buffer)], "%c", c);
    }
    close(fileptr);
    */         
     
    return buffer;
}
 
//convert bytes to file
void convertbytes(const char *buffer, const char *filename) {
    FILE *fileptr; 
    printf("%s .... %d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
    //for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), fileptr);
        //printf("%c :: %d\n", buffer[i], i);
    //}
     
    close(fileptr);
}
```

Right now, I'm only trying to copy the files correctly, so no sending over to server yet. With this code, I can copy text files fine, but another file, such as a .o file containing 6.0kb, will be copied with 8 bytes. I'm attempting to convert the file to bytes (ready to send somewhere) and then building a file from bytes. Am I approaching this wrong? Should I be using other means to do this? What is the correct way of build a simple FTP?

Comment: I see you have commented out the use of `sprintf` and `strlen`. These functions only work with strings - text, which binary data is not. If you want to move binary data around you must use `memcpy` (or `memmove`) instead of `strcpy`. In the old days when sending binary data by RS232, to distinguish the data from the protocol, one way was to split each data byte into two nibbles, sending each as hex text.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1006797/694576

Comment: BTW, FTP *is* a *standard*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol Will your code confirm to this? If not, better do not call it FTP.

Comment: Im attempting a simple FTP not a full FTP. I believe Hugal is right since `fwrite` is using `strlen` it is not reading the full file. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Binary files, or indeed any files, already are bytes. `fwrite()` does not use `strlen()`. Unclear what on earth you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your buffer is filled with binary data.
Binary data can contain a null character (\0, or 0x00), and it is not compatible with `strlen`, since `strlen` will stop at the first null character.

You can try something like that to return the actual lenght of the file:

```
struct buffer {
    char  *buffer;
    size_t filelen;
}

struct buffer *convertfile(const char *filename)
{
     ...
}
```

And:

```
struct buffer * filecpy = convertfile("mtg.jpg");
printf("%.*s .... %d\n",filecpy.filelen, filecpy.buffer, filecpy.filelen);
```